# TypeError: Object IE <= 11 has no method 'startsWith'

Tags: node.js, webpack, react-redux, babeljs

I am about to deploy my project on a ECS server. It works fine on the local machine, but after the regular routine, `npm run build` and then `npm run start`. The application exits with a very wired error.

```
/root/redux-blog/public/assets/server.js:1
on(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e,t,n,r){if(e===n)return !0;if(!n.startsWith
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Object IE <= 11 has no method 'startsWith'
    at r (server.js:4:4318)
    at Object.isBrowser (server.js:4:4530)
    at Object.isBrowser (server.js:42:27341)
    at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:41:15829)
    at t (server.js:1:182)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.create.constructor.value (server.js:41:11850)
    at t (server.js:1:182)
    at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:41:3056)
    at t (server.js:1:182)
    at Object.module.exports.n (server.js:41:7630)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

I thought it should be the `polyfill` issue. then add `require('string.prototype.startswith');` in the webpack file. it still not works.

1. The used OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64.
2. project link : [redux blog](https://github.com/ryuever/redux-blog)

Comment: What is in this file /root/redux-blog/public/assets/server.js? there's no such file in redux blog

Comment: It is server rending packing file and created by `npm run build`,

Comment: Where did you add the polyfill? Adding it to your webpack file does nothing, it has to be in your app

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the reason and the reason is low Node.js version.